# Load page on certain section

Tags: javascript

I have a simple webpage with a 3 section format that scrolls horizontally. I want the page to load on the middle section. I've found a couple of solutions on here but none of them have worked. Maybe I'm not doing them right. I'm not experienced in coding.

I know I can't use anchor tags for the url because it's for my main page so visitors have to put in the web address. There has to be a simple solution for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the [`ScrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) method.

Comment: Consider using [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle section should look like this:

```
<section id="mainSection" tabindex="1">
</section>
```

And on windows load, the focus() function should work:

```
$("#mainSection").focus();//jQuery
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById("mainSection").focus();//JavaScript
```

Comment: It took some work to make it harmonize with my page builder but it works great. Thanks